# How is the section in the evaluation called where you discuss the practical use of an artifact?

Tags: thesis, evaluation, conclusion-section

my supervisor recommended me that I add a section that discusses the application of the artefact that I previously evaluated in a research environment in a real-world use case.

I should use runtime (is it fast enough) and costs (how much does the executing cost), so do I discuss whether it is worth using it. And it is, of course.

Is there a typical name for such a section?

To name it "Discussion" seems too general to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ask your supervisor. They should know the conventions in your field. Perhaps wait to ask this question until you have a draft of the section to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There ae many possibilities. Assuming that you developed the artifact and that the paper discusses its technical qualities you could, perhaps do one of the following.

- A section titled "Practical Implications", before the Conclusions
- An Appendix, following the Conclusions.

If your advisor has different advice it is probably worth taking it.

Comment: what about discussion on practical applicability

Comment: That would work fine.

Comment: I am not sure about the position of this section. Would it be part of the evaluation section as a subsection after the subsection "results"? or would it be an own section since such a discussion is not part of the evaluation? I am not sure what is the default. However, adding it in the last section "conclusion and future work", it is too much content and I am using specific numbers and calculations in this discussion which is not appropriate in this section. Any thoughts? Any defaults or rules?

Comment: If it is a bit different from the rest then I'd guess it would be its own section just before Conclusions, or, again, an Appendix. But, not a rule, really, just something that makes sense and is clear.